# OpenGL normal mapping calculations

Tags: java, opengl, normals

I've got a question about some code that I found on the internet without further explanation.

It is about the calculation for normal mapping.
On my vertex shader, I got a uniform variable (vec3) of the light position. But the position of the light got premultiplied with the view matrix. So the light position is accessed relative to the camera.

The Java code looks like this: (note that I work with multiple lights, this has no influence on the calculation itself; `super.loadVector()` uploads a uniform vector).

```
public void loadLights(List<Light> lights, Matrix4f viewMatrix){
    super.loadFloat(this.location_lightAmount, Math.min(RenderSettings.ENTITIES_MAX_LIGHTS,lights.size()));
    for(int i=0;i<RenderSettings.ENTITIES_MAX_LIGHTS;i++){
        if(i<lights.size()){
            super.loadVector(location_lightPositionEyeSpace[i], getEyeSpacePosition(lights.get(i), viewMatrix));
            super.loadVector(location_lightColor[i], lights.get(i).getColor());
            super.loadVector(location_lightAttenuation[i], lights.get(i).getAttenuation());
        }
    }
}

public static Vector3f getEyeSpacePosition(Light light, Matrix4f viewMatrix){
    Vector3f position = light.getAbsolutePosition();
    Vector4f eyeSpacePos = new Vector4f(position.x,position.y, position.z, 1f);
    Matrix4f.transform(viewMatrix, eyeSpacePos, eyeSpacePos);
    return new Vector3f(eyeSpacePos);
}
```

This makes no sense to me because the camera position should have no influence on the calculation of the normals, right?

The next thing is following: When I render without normal mapping I transform the normal of each vertex by using the transformation matrix like this:

```
in vec3 normal;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;

void(main) {
    //........
    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(normal,0.0)).xyz;
    //........
}
```

However, this calculation is not applied in the normal mapping code that I found. Here, the normal (and the tangent) is multiplied with the viewMatrix and transformationMatrix like this:

```
mat4 modelViewMatrix = viewMatrix * transformationMatrix;
vec3 surfaceNormal = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(normal,0.0)).xyz;
```

The bitangent can be easily calculated with the surfaceNormal and the surfaceTangent calculated. The tangentSpaceMatrix is then used for transforming the light position. **But why is the view matrix used for all the transformations?**

The way that I understood normal mapping is the following: transform the whole system, so that the triangle (that is being rendered) lies flat on the ground (tangent space). Then the normal equals the RGB-value of the normal map.
(I know that this might sound a little bit confusing, I hope you understand what I mean).

Greetings, Finn

Comment: I haven't looked at the code yet. However be advised that the camera position has an influence on reflection vectors, which effects on things like specular highlights. This is one of the reasons why illumination calculations usually are done in eye space.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the orientation of the normals has nothing to do with the camera. The calculation of the specular light is influenced by the camera, that's true :)

Comment: The lighting computations can be done in world space or eye space, It is just a matter of preference, I guess the code sample you found is just using camera-space lighting

Comment: So, I could just remove the viewMatrix from every calculation ?

Comment: As long as you are consistent, yeah you can choose the space where you compute the lighting